# Arduino boards are not working with powerbanks!

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, power, oled

I have used many Arduino boards with adapters and other power supplies. While connecting with a powerbank for portable projects I have noticed that the power goes off after a couple of seconds and then turn on again after sometimes. Why this is happening with power bank?
I have used following powerbanks:

1. Basus
2. Xiaomi

Comment: refer to the powerbank datasheet for minimum and maximum allowable load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most USB powerbanks will automatically turn off if there is not a minimum current draw to keep them turned on.  The Arduino is obviously drawing current below the limit for the devices you have.

A couple of options:

1. Add some additional load to keep the powerbank on indefinitely.  Of course this may waste power but that's part of the price to pay.
2. Find a power bank that is less sophisticated.  I have one with a manual on/off switch.  It powers the Arduino just fine until it runs out of power.
3. Find a different powerbank that has a lower threshold for staying on.  Some vendors give you this spec and others don't.
4. Modify the powerbank to stay on.  I'm not sure there is a general way to do this but you might experiment with it and see.

Comment: Any links to indicate power banks automatically turn off below a certain current or power threshold after a certain time would be useful, even if they are just links to user manuals you are familiar with.

Comment: I thought it was a working method of powerbank . Thanks for the suggestion.